# How to add multiple objects to local storage with the same key

Tags: javascript

I have this piece of code that reads data from an excel sheet, turns them into objects and then display their details in a neat product card

```
let allHoodies = [
  ['Hoodie', 'Purple', 'Cotton', '$39.99', 'image/items/hoodies/hoodie(1).jpg'],
  ['Hoodie', 'Blue', 'Cotton', '$39.99', 'image/items/hoodies/hoodie(2).jpg'],
  ['Hoodie', 'Green', 'Cotton', '$39.99', 'image/items/hoodies/hoodie(3).jpg']
]

allHoodies.forEach((element, index) => {
  let obj = {}
  obj.id = index
  obj.type = element[0]
  obj.color = element[1]
  obj.material = element[2]
  obj.price = element[3]
  obj.imagesrc = element[4]
  allHoodies[index] = obj
})

//Evaluating each hoodie and displaying its information in HTML
allHoodies.forEach(function(hoodie) {
  let card = `
        <div class="card">
            <img class="product-image" src="${hoodie.imagesrc}">
            <h1 class="product-type">${hoodie.type}</h1>
            <p>Color: ${hoodie.color}</p>
            <p>${hoodie.material} <a href="#" onclick="addToStorage(${hoodie.id})">Read more</a> </p>
            <p class="price">${hoodie.price}</p>
            <p><button>Buy</button></p>
        </div>
    `;

  // Add the card to the page
  document.getElementById('product-container').innerHTML += card;
});
```

What I'm trying to do is, upon clicking "Buy", it adds multiple items to the local storage although I'm struggling to do it and add multiple ones, it keeps on adding only 1 of them and overwriting the previous one (I'm assuming due to the fact that they have the same key)

Here's what I've tried (which works, but its not my goal):

```
function addToCart(id){
    let hoodie = hoodies[id];
    localStorage.setItem('item', JSON.stringify(hoodie));
}
```

and then I simply add the `addToCart()` function to the button, would someone guide me and help me figure out how I could actually add multiple ones to the local storage and not just keep overwriting?
Expected result:
[image: expected result]

[Runnable JSFiddle snippet](http://jsfiddle.net/mozzenberg/0eny7vfq/18/)

Comment: Simple answer is store whole array of objects. When you need to modify pull array from storage do modification then store again

Comment: Thing is that that's not my goal, I want to add specific elements of the objects array, for example (if you check out my [snippet](http://jsfiddle.net/mozzenberg/0eny7vfq/18/)), I want to add the purple and green hoodie, but not the blue one,  I want all of their data to be stored in local storage, That's what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: You need to append to previous data otherwise you will overwriting that key value.

Comment: use `localStorage.getItem("item")` and parse it then try to add.

Comment: Fine...you use a completely different array for the cart vs allHoodies. Each time you change something in cart you store modified cart array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`localStorage#getItem`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem) to get the current list, and [`JSON#parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to convert it to an array of objects. Then, use [`Array#push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) to add the current item, and finally, use [`localStorage#set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem) and [`JSON#stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) to save the updated list:

```
function addToCart(id) {
  try {
    const hoodie = allHoodies[id];
    if(hoodie) {
      const items = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('items') || "[]");
      items.push(hoodie);
      localStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify(items));
    }
  } catch(e) {
    console.log('error adding item');
  }
}
```

Function to show the saved list:

```js
function displayProductsinCart() {
  const products = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("item") || "[]");
  document.getElementById("item-container").innerHTML = products.reduce((cards, product) =>
    cards + `<div class="card">
            <img class="item-image" src="${product.image}">
            <h1 class="product-type">${product.type}</h1>
            <p>Color: ${product.color}</p>
             <p>${product.description}</p>
            <p class="price">${product.price} </p>
            <p><button>Buy</button></p>
        </div>
    `, '');
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the valuable information you've provided, although when I tried running the code it didn't work for some reason, am I doing something wrong?
[Snippet](http://jsfiddle.net/mozzenberg/0eny7vfq/23/)

Comment: How are you testing it? I ran your snippet while monitoring the local storage in the dev tools and it's adding the items..

Comment: My apologies, I just realized that the values are getting updated within the same localStorage file

Comment: I've got another question if you don't mind me asking, how would I approach reading the data so I can display the items in the local storage in a neat way in a "cart.html" page?
I wrote some pseudocode in this [Snippet](http://jsfiddle.net/mozzenberg/0eny7vfq/37/)
How would you approach this?

Comment: I updated the answer with a possible solution, feel free to ask other questions here

Comment: That's all, thank you so much!